# What is my port of entry into India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, canadian-citizens

I intend to visit India this Christmas. I am a Canadian citizen and plan to use the [Indian e-Tourist Visa](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html). This visa is usually applied for and issued online.

I am travelling on Jet Airways from Doha (DOH) - Mumbai (BOM) - Ahmedabad (AMD). One of the fields on the visa applications asks for my port of entry and I was unsure as to whether it is Mumbai or Ahmedabad. I have a layover in Mumbai for about 3 hours before boarding for AMD.

I have called the airline (Jet Airways) and they told me it should be Ahmedabad but to confirm with an embassy or consulate. The guy on the other end didn't sound very sure either.

What is my port of entry into India for immigration purposes?

Comment: Depends whether you go through immigration in Mumbai during the layover.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is my port of entry into India for immigration purposes?

From the official [Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport](http://www.csia.in/passenger/immigration.aspx) Immigration link:

On arrival, **all passengers** are requested to move towards Immigration. **We conduct immigration check for all passengers, Indians or foreigners, both at the time of arrival and departure**. The passports are duly stamped at time of arrival as well as departure.

Which means all passengers must go to immigration first.

Also a link from [India Visa Faq](http://www.passportvisasexpress.com/visa_services/india/country_information/indian_visa_faq) confirms the same:

• **What is the Port of Arrival in India?**

The port of arrival is the location at which you first enter India. Your port of arrival is the name of the city where you initially enter India.

Therefore, Mumbai is your port of entry also you can write Mumbai in your visa form.

Answer (score 5):

For any country, the port of entry is the location where you clear immigration. This is almost always the first place you land in a country that has immigration facilities, and this doesn't appear to be an exception.

The first port of entry you will reach on this itinerary is Mumbai, and that is where you will clear immigration before changing to the domestic flight.

So you should put Mumbai as the port of entry.